# Zsh global alias equivalent in fish shell

Tags: terminal, alias, fish

In Zsh I use the following global alias:

```
alias -g L='| less --chop-long-lines'
```

When executing `echo "hello world" L` in Zsh, `less` will display the sentence 'hello world'.
How to write a fish function equivalent to a Zsh global alias?

Comment: Nope. fish aliases are just syntactic sugar for functions.

Comment: @glennjackman  As is evident from the question, I know that fish only has functions. The question is therefore how to write a fish function acting like a Zsh global alias. I tried it myself but my test functions never worked as expected and as I couldn't find  the answer online, I asked on stackoveflow. Maybe such a function can't be written in fish, or I've overlooked a little thing and it's no problem at all.

Comment: The only way I can see to code your specific example is : `function L; env $argv | less --chop-long-lines; end` and invoke with `L echo "hello world"` -- obviously using a function as a command, not like a zsh global alias.

Comment: There seems to be now way to evaluate arguments if they match with a function name. The idea to prefix the entered command with the L function name is okay. Having it at the end seems more natural to me, but okay, no one can have everything. Therefore I suggest that you answer my question with something like a 'it's not possible...' and I will accept it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zsh's global alias feature is unique to zsh.
fish cannot recognize aliases except where you'd expect a command, as the first word.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the equivalent of global aliases in fish using [Abbreviations](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/interactive.html#abbreviations).

With the command `abbr` you can expand a word or a regex to a command at any position in the typed command.

```bash
abbr --add L --position anywhere '| less --chop-long-lines'
```